# react hooks and antd to create form, when I input something,the input will blur

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd

I code a form component with react hooks and antd,
but when I type something ,the input will blur.

[the code page](https://codesandbox.io/s/z6r3zlxxrl)

Answer (score 0):

Problem with usage, cell is a defined component

https://codesandbox.io/s/624j14393w